# Protractor: Can I proceed with execution of the test if I close browser earlier in it?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I have a question: Is it posible to continue with execution of one test, if I have earlier closed browser in it?

For example, I want to check is the user in my application logged in, even when I restart browser. I want to check that with and without "Remember me" checkbox.

After I login my user in app, I try with this:

```
browser.close();
```

but test ends and can not be continued further.
If i try with this:

```
browser.get("");
browser.get("about:blank");
```

only blank tab is open, and test ends.If I try with:

```
browser.quit();
```

than whole session is killed and test is ended,

If anyone knows solution, or have some ideas, please answer. Thanks

Comment: Hey @Dejan I am not sure of this.. but I found two methods attachSession and createSession in [this link](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.attachToSession). Have not used sessions concept in my life ever. If i do master this, will get back to you. Till then please refer the link.

Answer (score 2):

You'll be able to do this with the next release of Protractor, which includes the new `browser.forkNewDriverInstance` function. This lets you create a new instance of your browser via webdriver. See the commit (https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/0bbfd2b6d38392938781d846ad37b5a0fd964004) for more information.